# Unable to add text before and after a 3d scroll animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, gsap

I am trying to recreate a 3-D scroll animation from [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLbI7BGdQ3o][1]

Here i want to use this as a section between my website, but having a problem in adding elements or data above it and below it. I believe its due to fixed position. Tried several thing on changing it but it didn't worked.

Basically
i want to add `<div class="data-above">Data Here </div>` this div above this animated div with fixed position.Also data below it after end of animation.

```js
stickyElem = document.querySelector(".container");
     
/* Gets the amount of height
of the element from the
viewport and adds the
pageYOffset to get the height
relative to the page */
currStickyPos = stickyElem.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
     
    /* Check if the current Y offset
    is greater than the position of
    the element */
    if(window.pageYOffset > currStickyPos) {
        stickyElem.style.position = "fixed";
        stickyElem.style.top = "0px";
    } else {
        stickyElem.style.position = "relative";
        stickyElem.style.top = "initial";
    }
}
let zSpacing = -1000,
    lastPos = zSpacing / 5;
    $frames = document.getElementsByClassName('frame'),
    frames = Array.from($frames),
    zVals = [];

window.onscroll = function() {
    let top = document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        delta = lastPos - top;

    lastPos = top;

    frames.forEach(function(n, i) {
        zVals.push((i * zSpacing) + zSpacing);
        zVals[i] += delta * -5.5;
        let frame = frames[i],
            transform = `translateZ(${zVals[i]}px)`;
            opacity = zVals[i] < Math.abs(zSpacing) / 1.8 ? 1 : 0
        frame.setAttribute('style', `transform: ${transform}; opacity: ${opacity}`);
    });
};

window.scrollTo(0, 1);

// Audio

let soundButton = document.querySelector('.soundbutton'),
        audio = document.querySelector('.audio')

soundButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    soundButton.classList.toggle('paused')
    audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause()
})

window.onfocus = function() {
    soundButton.classList.contains('paused') ? audio.pause() : audio.play()
}

window.onblur = function() {
    audio.pause()
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: 0;
}

:root {
    --index: calc(1vw + 1vh);
    --gutter: 30px;
    --side-small: 26;
    --side-big:36;
    --depth: 4000px;
    --transition: .75s cubic-bezier(.075, .5, 0, 1);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: raleway_c;
    src: url(../fonts/raleway-v22-cyrillic-300.woff2);
    font-weight: 300;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: raleway_c;
    src: url(../fonts/raleway-v22-cyrillic-100.woff2);
    font-weight: 100;
}

body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: calc(var(--index) * .8);
    font-family: raleway_c, sans-serf;
    line-height: 1.75;
    height: var(--depth);
    font-weight: 300;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    perspective: 1500px; /* параметр для работы с трансформирование по оси Z */
}

.gallery {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
}

.frame {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: var(--transition), opacity .75s;
    will-change: transform;
    transform-style: preserve-3d; /* для более четкого шрифта, при увеличении */
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: min-content;
    line-height: 1;
}

.frame h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: calc(var(--index) * 3.3);
}

.frame-media {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(var(--index) * var(--side-small));
    height: calc(var(--index) * var(--side-big));
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.frame-media_left {
    right: calc(var(--side-small) / 2 * var(--index) + var(--gutter));
}

.frame-media_right {
    left: calc(var(--side-small) / 2 * var(--index) + var(--gutter));
}

.frame_bg {
    background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / .87);
}

video.frame-media {
    width: calc(var(--index) * var(--side-big));
    height: calc(var(--index) * var(--side-small));
}

video.frame-media_right {
    left: calc(var(--side-big) / 2 * var(--index) + var(--gutter));
}

video.frame-media_left {
    right: calc(var(--side-big) / 2 * var(--index) + var(--gutter));
}

.text-right > * {
    position: relative;
    left: 18vw;
}

.text-left > * {
    position: relative;
    right: 18vw;
}

.frame h3 {
    font-size: calc(var(--index) * 3);
}

.frame p {
    max-width: 30vw;
    margin-top: 3vh;
}

.soundbutton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5vh;
    right: 5vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 24px;
    transition: .25s ease;
}

.soundbutton.paused {
    opacity: .25;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

    <script src="js/app.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="data-above">
      
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <section class="gallery">
        <div class="frame">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <h2>Events</h2>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <div
              class="frame-media frame-media_left"
              style="background-image: url(images/1.jpg)"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <video
              class="frame-media frame-media_right"
              src="media/video_optimized.mp4"
              autoplay
              loop
              muted
            ></video>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame"></div>

        <div class="frame">
          <div class="frame__content text-right">
            <h3>Pure Planet</h3>
            <p>
              Is an innovative initiative dedicated to embracing nature's
              essence for a sustainable future. With a strong focus on
              environmental conservation and renewable energy, we aim to inspire
              individuals and businesses alike to adopt eco-friendly practices
              and reduce their carbon footprint. Join us on this journey towards
              a greener, cleaner planet, where harmony between humanity and
              nature is paramount. Together, we can make a profound difference
              and pave the way for a sustainable world.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <div
              class="frame-media frame-media_left"
              style="background-image: url(images/2.jpg)"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame"></div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <div
              class="frame-media frame-media_right"
              style="background-image: url(images/3.jpg)"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame"></div>

        <div class="frame">
          <div class="frame__content text-left">
            <h3>Ask the Mountains</h3>
            <p>
              In the tranquil embrace of nature, where the mountains stand tall
              and steadfast, lies a world of wonder waiting to be unraveled.
              "Ask the Mountains" is an adventurous expedition into the heart of
              these silent guardians, where nature's mysteries await
              exploration. Journey with us as we delve into the rugged terrains,
              witness breathtaking landscapes, and learn from the wisdom
              embedded in these ancient giants. Discover the interconnectedness
              of all life, as the mountains echo stories of resilience and
              harmony. Let us embark on this transformative quest to understand,
              respect, and protect the delicate balance that sustains our
              planet. Together, we can glean invaluable lessons from the
              mountains and forge a profound connection with the natural world
              around us. So, come, let us ask the mountains and unveil the
              secrets that lie within.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <div
              class="frame-media frame-media_right"
              style="background-image: url(images/4.jpg)"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <video
              class="frame-media frame-media_left"
              src="media/video_optimized.mp4"
              autoplay
              loop
              muted
            ></video>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame"></div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <div
              class="frame-media frame-media_right"
              style="background-image: url(images/5.jpg)"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame"></div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <video
              class="frame-media"
              src="media/video_optimized.mp4"
              autoplay
              loop
              muted
            ></video>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame"></div>
        <div class="frame"></div>

        <div class="frame">
          <div class="frame__content">© 2023 frontend-dev.com</div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>

    <img src="images/sound.gif" alt="Alt" class="soundbutton" />
    <audio src="media/ambient.mp3" class="audio" loop></audio>


        
  </body>
</html>
```

I also tried making a parent-container relative container nd making container-1 sticky, but it didnt worked.
i would really appreciate your time and help.
Thankyou in advance.
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLbI7BGdQ3o